# Windows 10 20H2 Not showing app thumbnails in task bar on secondary monitors

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, nvidia-graphics-card

I have a system with a fresh install of Windows 20H2, with an Nvidia 1080Ti graphics card. Normally when mousing over/clicking an open app icon with multiple windows (ie. chrome), I'd see a preview thumbnail for each open window. This works on my main monitor (AW3821DW). However, on the 2 secondary monitors I have, the preview thumbnails are black windows. If I minimize the application/window to the taskbar, then I see the preview thumbnails on my other monitors as expected.

All latest Windows Updates are installed, and I'm running the latest nvidia drivers (v461.72).

Comment: Perhaps update BIOS and all other related drivers for your machine. That would be a starting point.

Comment: Done. BIOS is on latest version, and all other drivers are updated.
I should note that I'm seeing this same behavior on 2 different systems. Just updated the motherboard/cpu/RAM from an Intel 4790k/Z97/DDR3 platform to an AMD 5900X/X570/DDR4 platform, with a fresh install of 20H2 for each, and seeing this behavior for both (same GPU used in both systems). Taskbar was behaving fine on Windows 1809 (which had gone through a few updates from 1703 I believe) before other issues triggered me to do a fresh Windows install.

Comment: Well, I don't have much of an explanation, but I reloaded windows, starting with 1909, and then upgrading to 20H2 in place. Doing so, my taskbar thumbnails are behaving properly. So there's definitely some issue with 20H2.